# Collateral Address for react app

Tags: wallet, collateral

how I can get users collateral address from wallet?

I am using nft-maker-pro for creating a small NFT market place. I need collateral address for that like https://d-wallet-playground.yellowhouse.gmbh/wallet this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the tool but the collateral is usually provided by whoever is creating the transaction to be submitted. And as long as a smart contract isn't being run and fails during validation your collateral is save.

So if you use a light wallet like nami send yourself 5-10 ADA and use that as collateral.

Comment: Is there any way to get that address?

Comment: It's your own wallet address. You can just copy it when you have Nami installed and setup.

Answer (score 0):

According to [CIP-30](https://developers.cardano.org/docs/governance/cardano-improvement-proposals/CIP-0030)

"api.getCollateral()"

so you can get it in your react application by using:

```
const api = await window.cardano[WALLET-NAME].enable()
const changeAddress = await api.getCollateral()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get a collateral UTXO is to use a library like Helios which is both an on-chain smart contract Plutus compiler and an off-chain transaction builder.   Helios has some convenience wrappers/helpers for working with CIP30 spec so you don’t have to do the CBOR conversions for example.

Here is the code.

```
    // Determine the UTXO used for collateral
    const colatUtxo = await walletHelper.pickCollateral();
    
    tx.addCollateral(colatUtxo);
```

Or if you need the change wallet address, you can use.

```
// Get change address
const changeAddr = await walletHelper.changeAddress;
```

Check out the full source code here in my Helios examples repo:  https://github.com/lley154/helios-examples/blob/main/nft/pages/index.tsx